# web3js eth vs account vs personal

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

web3.eth, web3.eth.personal, web3.eth.accounts look similar to me. As they all have same functions - sign, sendtransaction and etc. What is a good way to apply those packages on certain situations? I mean, how could we decide when to use each of the packages?

When I looked through the documentation, it tells me

1) web3.eth - interacting with ethereum blockchain and smartcontract

2) web3.eth.personal - interact with ethereum' nodes account

3) web3.eth.accounts - generate ethereum accounts and sign transactions and data

Does that mean I could manage a local node with personal package and others with accounts?

Comment: Please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: @NagaSaiA Yeah I would upload it in a few hours. I didn't complete it yet and that is the reason why I am asking what kind of package that I need to use. I understand that it would much better if I upload codes. I would definitely upload it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included a reference to a more thorough medium article below on the topic.

But for the short answer.
When using the web3.eth.accounts package, actions should be performed on the local node, because when the operations are performed on the local, the private keys will not be sent out to the network and they are safe.

You can use web3.eth.personal when you are working with another entity's account.  Whatever password/information you send will be used by another node, as such you don't use this package to create user accounts or store keys;

https://medium.com/@andthentherewere0/should-i-use-web3-eth-accounts-or-web3-eth-personal-for-account-creation-15eded74d0eb

Comment: Great. It was a big help to me. I need to use eth.account package rather than eth.personal to make an account. I have a question, what are the cases when we are working with another entity's account? 

I am now working on DApp which is managing user accounts on local node running on server. I don't actually get when to work with another entity's account. 

Would it be a better idea just to make an account and signTransaction on local node rather than working with another entity's account? Because we could sign on local node and just sendTransaction on network.

Comment: This is almost same issue, when to use eth.sign vs eth.accounts.sign vs eth.personal.sign. This is exactly what @Legman told me. I am sharing this to help other people who are reading this question.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25601/what-is-the-difference-between-web3-eth-sign-web3-e

Comment: Could you tell me what is different from web3js.eth vs web3js.eth.accounts?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented reflecting answer from Legman. I used ganache and web3js to transfer ether from one to another. PrivateKey is changing every time when it is connected to ganache.

```
// (Web3js) Test making transaction from one account to another in ganache
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function (accounts) { // NOTE : to reduce latency, add relevant data to database
var senderAddress = accounts[0]
var receiverAddress = accounts[1]

// Balance before transaction
var checkSenderBalance = function () {
return web3.eth.getBalance(senderAddress)
  .then(function (balance) {console.log(balance)})
  .catch(function (error) {console.log(error)})
}

var checkReceiverBalance = function () {
return web3.eth.getBalance(receiverAddress)
  .then(function (balance) {console.log(balance)})
  .catch(function (error) {console.log(error)})
}

var rawTx = {
  from: senderAddress,
  to: receiverAddress,
  gasPrice: '200',
  gas: '210000',
  value: '1000',
  data: '' // NOTE : need to serialize and make it as HEX code to send data
}

// Case1 : Log into account with privateKey and signTransaction
var privateKey = '0xf8d19b3c72f27a9db1a71f73d229afe5980419928b0b33232efb4033494f1562'
var sender = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey) // Object to call signTransaction
var makeTransaction = function () {
  return sender.signTransaction(rawTx)
  .then(function (signedTx) {
    return web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
  })
  .then(function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
}

// Case2 : signTransaction using privateKey
var privateKey = '0xf8d19b3c72f27a9db1a71f73d229afe5980419928b0b33232efb4033494f1562'
var makeTransaction = function () {
  return web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTx, privateKey)
    .then(function (signedTx) {
    return web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
  })
  .then(function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
  // Case3 : Using Personal package
  // var makeTransaction = web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(senderAddress, '')
//   .then(function (result) {
//     if (result) return web3.eth.personal.signTransaction(rawTx, '')
//   })
//   .then(function (signedTx) {
//     return web3.eth.personal.sendTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
//   })
//   .catch(function (error) {
//     console.log(error)
//   })

checkSenderBalance()
.then(checkReceiverBalance)
.then(makeTransaction)
.then(checkSenderBalance)
.then(checkReceiverBalance)
.catch(function (error) {console.log(error)})
})
```

Comment: One thing to notice. Case3 is not working because some functions are not supported yet.